# Is there a header identifying SunOS/Solaris version at compile time?

Tags: c++, c, solaris

I am trying to detect Solaris/SunOS version at compile time so that I can enable/disable use of [`port_create()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5168/port-create-3c.html#REFMAN3Aport-create-3c) and other APIs.

Is there a header identifying SunOS/Solaris version at compile time?

Answer (score 3):

If no header is giving you this information, you could of course parse the output of `uname` and generate `-D` preprocessor option(s) from your build script/makefile/...

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating upon the suggestion by @[meaning-matters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1971013/meaning-matters), one can make a compile-time definition, say `SUN_VERSION` using the output of `uname -r`.  That actually gives a floating point number, e.g., `5.10`, which you could convert into a preprocessor-comparable form using a simple sed command, e.g., this compiler option:

```
-DSUN_VERSION=`uname -r | sed -e 's/\.\([0-9]\{1,1\}\)$/0\1/' -e 's/\.//'`
```

produces `510` for `5.10`, `509` for `5.9`, etc.

In your source program, you could use it like this

```
#if SUN_VERSION >= 510
```

(or whatever makes sense).

Comment: That's what I mean; very nice! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Identifying the OS release in order to assert an `API` is available or not is risky if not doomed. You cannot assume an `API` will stay in future releases nor if it is available in a parallel branch (eg. Illumos vs Solaris 11 which are both reporting `SunOS 5.11` as their version).

The usual way to overcome this issue is simply to check if the `API` is available by compiling a small test source code to figure it out. This is usually done in a script traditionally named `configure` that builds a `Makefile` and an include file tailored to your system.

Answer (score -2):

To expand upon @meaning-matters answer, use GNU make, and [set a variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Setting) to the OS version.  Pass that variable on to the compiler using the `-D` command-line option.

Makefile:

```
OS_VERSION := $(shell uname -r)
version:
    $(CC) -DOS_VERSION=$(OS_VERSION) version.c -o version
test:
    echo $(OS_VERSION)
```

version.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
int main()
{
    printf( "OS Version: " TOSTRING(OS_VERSION) "\n" );
    return( 0 );
}
```

Output:

```
bash 4.1$ gmake test
echo 5.11
5.11
bash 4.1$ gmake version
cc -DOS_VERSION=5.11 version.c -o version
bash 4.1$ ./version
OS Version: 5.11
bash 4.1$
```

Use `:=` (assign if not already set) to only run the `uname` command once.

That will show "5.10" for Solaris 10, "5.11" for Solaris 11.

Comment: You don't need gnu-make to do this procedure (it's doable with ordinary shell commands from a makefile).

Comment: @ThomasDickey I'm sure of it.  Post your solution too as an answer.  But I've become so used to using GNU make - even on Solaris - that I just default to it at all times now.  GNU extensions have become commonplace even on Solaris.  I'm pretty sure even parts of OpenSolaris (prior to Oracle shutting it down) had to be built with GNU make.  And I hope you didn't downvote me for that...